# Why the PHP Framework Laravel deprecate Route FEATURE "controller" since version 5.2?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I used to use Framework Laravel 5.x routes as follows:

```
Route::controller("demo", "\App\Http\Controllers\DemoController");
```

But when I read the routing codes in Laravel 5.2, I see it has been deprecated since version 5.2, in file \Illuminate\Routing\Router

```
/**
 * Route a controller to a URI with wildcard routing.
 *
 * @param  string  $uri
 * @param  string  $controller
 * @param  array  $names
 * @return void
 *
 * @deprecated since version 5.2.
 */
public function controller($uri, $controller, $names = [])
{
    $prepended = $controller;

    // First, we will check to see if a controller prefix has been registered in
    // the route group. If it has, we will need to prefix it before trying to
    // reflect into the class instance and pull out the method for routing.
    if (! empty($this->groupStack)) {
        $prepended = $this->prependGroupUses($controller);
    }

    $routable = (new ControllerInspector)
                        ->getRoutable($prepended, $uri);

    // When a controller is routed using this method, we use Reflection to parse
    // out all of the routable methods for the controller, then register each
    // route explicitly for the developers, so reverse routing is possible.
    foreach ($routable as $method => $routes) {
        foreach ($routes as $route) {
            $this->registerInspected($route, $controller, $method, $names);
        }
    }

    $this->addFallthroughRoute($controller, $uri);
}
```

I think this is a good feature, but why they deprecate it ?

Are there any other better solutions ?

= Update 1 =

As the issue ( https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/10777 ) said, he thought that feature makes the routes confusing, or easy leading access to unexpected route definitions.

Comment: That's a question best asked for the devs of laravel don't you think?

Comment: I think so, however could we find the reason ?

Comment: doesn't seem to give any reasons... https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/10782 if its deprecated there is a better way to do it

Comment: Have you looked into resource controllers? Also you can achieve the same thing with `Route::get()`

Comment: Yeah, this feature certainly can be achieved with the basic uses of `Route::any/get/post...`.

I just wonder if we can define something to prevent the confusing route definitions, thus avoid the deprecation.

Comment: I think it was deprecated because it's better to be explicit instead of implicit when defining routes. This isn't a question for StackOverflow though.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's better directed at the developers, since it's a "why did they do this" question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Github Issue (https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/10777)

rkgrep  says:

This method has quite a lot of issues and also makes routes definitions confusing as they are not directly referenced in routes file. This sometimes may lead to unexpected route definitions (e. g. if method like getFilesystem is added to parent or trait - developer mistake, but may be unnoticed).

It also may cause security mistakes when middleware is applied on specific methods (e. g. someone adds new method to controller and forgets to add middleware), which arise rarely when routes are defined manually.

And at last - parameters issue, which is hard to fix because of grouping or other unexpected route combinations (See #10774).

To decrease amount of breaks it should be marked as deprecated in next 5.1.x release.

Possible alternative: mark this method as deprecated in master and remove in next major release.